# Android Studio 3.2 beta 2 and 3.3 canary 2 freezes every time

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio version 3.2 beta 2 and 3.3 canary 2 both of them freezes every time while using. I had tried the previous versions which used to work properly except few of the features.

Comment: I am also having the same issue in both Android Studio.

Comment: 3.2 works fine for me, after a LONG days having problem with 3.1.3 I've fixed it with 3.2 about 1 month ago, after that im not gonna update it to a higher version till I be sure that everything is totally fine with the version, im recommending the same thing for everyone Im using 3.2 Canary Build 17 Download it and never update again #AndroidStudio #MotherBuger

Comment: I think the issue is related to adb. Kill the adb process from task manager and restart the android studio. It might solve the issue temporarily. 

I have also installed Android Studio 3.3 Canary 2 without importing any settings from the previous version. It is also working for me as of now.

Comment: 3.2. from the stable channel also hangs for me all the time. Almost unusable. Takes a few minutes to recover from each hang. I haven't switched to beta/canary channels on this computer.

Comment: 3.2.1. Stable (stable my ass) same issue, unusable. Is anybody aware of the issue ticket?

Comment: Feel free to vote/report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=android%20studio%20freeze

Comment: Have you tried the newest 3.4 canaries? They have a lot of fixes for the freezes.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I haven't tried yet. Thanks for the suggestion.